# How to create database on SQL Server 2017 instead of LocalDB or SQL Express via Code-First Entity Framework approach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, sql-server-2017

Actually, the title already summarizes my whole problem. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and Entity Framework 6. In my MVC application, when I follow code-first approach, with default settings I was only given options of either LocalDB or SQL Server Express to use in the SQL Server Object Explorer. I am able to see corresponding tables for my models in action using SQL Express.

However, I want to use my SQL Server 2017. I guess I must specify my desired DB in connection string but I could not figure out how to do that with Entity Framework 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just open your project `web.config` file, or the `app.config` file, then update your entity framework connection string to refer to the SQL Server instance you need just like below:

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=YourServerInstance;Initial Catalog=YourDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123456;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Make sure that you are editing the right connection string by checking your context class to check which connection string key name it refers:

```
public YourContext(bool lasyLoadingEnabled) : base("DefaultConnection")
{
    Database.SetInitializer<NimasContext>(null);
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = lasyLoadingEnabled;
    this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; ;
}
```

You can follow this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj556606(v=vs.113).aspx